# Why is js autoconverse my datetime to string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi i have small isiu with my metod...

```js
updateGeneralSettings(name, value) {
  console.log(value); //Here is value 2015-06-17 14:24:36
  const newData = {...this.state.data};
  newData.userData = {
    ...newData.userData,
    [name]: value,
  };
  console.log(newData); //Here is value "2015-06-17 14:24:36" ->string

  this.setState({data: newData});
}
```

I am sending name and value to my method. Value should be dateTime in this case. When i console log this at first line it is ok.... But when i add this value to [name] property it is changing to string... Why it is happening please? And how can I avoid this behaviour? Thx

I am passing data like this:

```js
submitButton() {
  var dateTime = Date.now();
  dateTime = moment(dateTime).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

  console.log(dateTime);
  this.props.updateGdpr('gdpr', dateTime); //This is method above but i am sending it to child like pros and it is renamed updateGdpr
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data for `name` and `value`?

Comment: name = 'gdpr', value = 2015-06-17 14:24:36

Comment: So `value` is passed in as a string?

Comment: dateTime is a string. so value is a string.

Comment: `moment.format` returns a string. If you want a `Date` in `state.userData[name]` you also have to pass in a `Date`.